# Touble in Python integer not iterate-able in nested for loop to store in list

Tags: python

I am in trouble writing a script to scan folded file size and store those data in a list.

Here is my current program:

```
import os
def getTotalFileSize(mypath):
    mydir = os.getcwd() + mypath
    list_file = os.listdir(mydir)
    for path in list_file:
        realpath =  mydir + '/' + path
        stateinfo = os.stat(realpath)
        stateinfo = stateinfo.st_size
        print(stateinfo)


mydir = '/testdir'
getTotalFileSize(mydir)
```

**Instruction for you:** Choose a folder/directory where a few numbers of files exist and then run this script, this script only scene file size of a directory.

**Problem:** When I run the script, it prints me like this:

```
456
345
23
4466
4446
```

But I don't need this. I need it in the list like

```
[456, 345, 23, 4466, 4446]
```

Can anyone please fix this problem

Comment: make a `list`, and append the `stateinfo` to that ?

Comment: Start [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import os

def getTotalFileSize(mypath):

```
size_list = []

mydir = os.getcwd() + mypath

list_file = os.listdir(mydir)

for path in list_file:

    realpath =  mydir + '/' + path

    stateinfo = os.stat(realpath)

    stateinfo = stateinfo.st_size

    size_list.append(stateinfo)

print(size_list)
```

mydir = '/testdir'

getTotalFileSize(mydir)

Answer (score 1):

Create a `list` and append the values from `stateinfo` to it, perhaps:

```
import os

def getTotalFileSize(mypath):
    stateInfo_lst = []                  # an empty list to store the values
    mydir = os.getcwd() + mypath
    list_file = os.listdir(mydir)
    for path in list_file:
        realpath =  mydir + '/' + path
        stateinfo = os.stat(realpath)
        stateinfo = stateinfo.st_size
        stateInfo_lst.append(stateinfo)   # appending the values to the list 
    print(stateInfo_lst)                  # printing the list after the loop


mydir = '/testdir'
getTotalFileSize(mydir)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[456, 345, 23, 4466, 4446]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
def getTotalFileSize(mypath):
  mydir = os.getcwd() + mypath
  list_file = os.listdir(mydir)
  stateList=[]
  for path in list_file:
    realpath =  mydir + '/' + path
    stateinfo = os.stat(realpath)
    stateinfo = stateinfo.st_size
    stateList.append(stateinfo)

mydir = '/testdir'
getTotalFileSize(mydir)
```

You can create new list like stateList and append your stateinfo values into list.

Comment: No no, it return this : [4]
[4, 4]
[4, 4, 18]
[4, 4, 18, 18]
[4, 4, 18, 18, 4]

Comment: I need only one list but it return multiple list, this is the problem